# How to get custom metabox image field?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox

i have custom metabox with the image field, i can upload image from wp-admin to this metabox, metabox code

```
array(
            'name' => 'Burst Image',
            'desc' => 'Crop your image to exact dimension before upload!',
            'id' => 'burst_img',
            'type' => 'image'
        )
```

i have code like `$burst_img= get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'burst_img', true );` to get the metabox , but it doesn't work, how can i get the metabox image ?

Comment: what are you storing in your database from metabox in post meta means `image id` or `image url`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, the WordPress function for displaying the image of your custom meta box is this `<?php wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size, $icon ); ?>`

Comment: Thanks, i need to get burst_img field from the metabox, meaning that get image uploaded for burst_img , what is $attachment_id here ?

Comment: i got it by `$burst_img = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'burst_img',true); 
    $burst_img=wp_get_attachment_image_src( $burst_img, 'full' );`